# Where did I make a mistake?

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

This is an excerpt from a dynamical systems paper:

[image]

They provide a proof of this Lemma, and numerical simulations also show it should be true. It's clear the equilibrium point on each axis is $\left(\sqrt{\frac{l}{-a}},0,0\right)$, $\left(0, \sqrt{\frac{l}{-a}},0\right)$, and $\left(0,0,\sqrt{\frac{l}{-a}}\right)$. I was doing linear stability analysis, and I started by computing the Jacobian:

$$
J \equiv
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\,{l+3ax^2+by^2+cz^2} & 2bxy & 2cxz
\\
2cxy & \,l+3ay^2+bz^2+cx^2 & 2byz
\\
\, 2bxz & 2cyz & {l+3az^2+bx^2+cy^2}
\end{array}\right)
$$

Evaluating the matrix at the first fixed point for example gives:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\,{-2l} & 0 & 0
\\
0 & \,-2l & 0
\\
\, 0 & 0 & {-2l}
\end{array}\right)
$$

For $l=1$, this says that all the eigenvalues are negative, so that this fixed point is stable from all directions (and in fact is independent of what $a,b,c$ are. But the paper provides a proof that a cycle should exist, so I'd expect each point to be a saddle. I must've made a mistake in the Jacobian, but for the life of me, I haven't been able to see where it is.

Comment: your calculations are correct. what is the definition of "cycle?" is it really required that any point on the cycle traverse the whole loop indefinitely, or does it suffice that a point on the cycle not leave the cycle?

Comment: @hunter I've always seen the definition to involve a sequence of fixed points with orbits connecting them. An example with this particular set of ODEs can be seen here: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Heteroclinic_cycles#The_Guckenheimer-Holmes_Cycle

Comment: ah nevermind! i made a mistake checking, maybe the same one you did -- see the answer by Mark Fischler below.

Comment: @hunter Ah yes, I'm pretty sure we both made the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the middle entry in the Jacobian: At the first fixed point it is not $-2\ell$, it is$$\ell \left( 1-\frac{c}{a} \right)$$ not $-2\ell$.  Similarly the bottom right is $$\ell \left( 1-\frac{b}{a} \right)$$.  The latter is not negative, because $\frac ba < 1$, so this point is not a stable point, it is a saddle.

Comment: Ah thank you for finding my mistake. I feel like an idiot haha.